# correct use of Android onSaveInstanceState()

Tags: android, save, bundle, state

I'm experiencing some problems with the onRestoreInstanceState() method.
This SumWindow activity shows to the user some questions and it stores the user's score in the variables tries and rights. Problem: if the user presses back and then from the main menu the user presses "Play!" (where the SumWindow activity get creates) the score is reset to 0 out of  0. I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental with this save/loadthing. This is my code (simplified for easier reading)

```
public class SumWindow extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    int tries;
    int rights;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            tries = savedInstanceState.getInt("tries");
            right = savedInstanceState.getInt("right");
        }
        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            savedInstanceState.putInt("tries", tries);
            savedInstanceState.putInt("rights", rights);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            tries = savedInstanceState.getInt("tries");
            right = savedInstanceState.getInt("rights");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`onSaveInstanceState()` is not called when the user presses BACK.**

It is called when the user changes configuration.

The obvious solution I see here is save your values is preference when user presses back key.You can use following snippet ( Just for reference )

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //save values in preference
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Inside onCreate check if any values exsists in preference,If yes restore them.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I managed to use a class that keeps the score in a static var. It's evil and not OO but that's I dealt with it. I'll try implementing your suggestion. I'm gonna experiment with this Keyevent this weekend. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is that in OnRestoreInstanceState you're not checking if savedInstanceState is null.
You should change with:

```
if(savedInstanceState!=null){
  tries = savedInstanceState.getInt("tries");
  right = savedInstanceState.getInt("rights");
}
```

Sorry for my english!